# Double hierarchical visualization for inputs and outputs with center point (RL-LR)

Tags: visualization, vis.js, graph-visualization, vis.js-network

Given a point in a graph, I want to render all its inputs and outputs on each side of the layout, such that the inputs are on the left side, and the output on the right side.

Is that possible?

My only "hack" would be to double render it and overlap the starting node.